# Address Split Formula

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

Any idea on how I can separate an address in Excel. Currently I have about 300 addresses that are in the flowing format:

1234 Address City, AL 55555

I have looked online and I have found out how to separate the city and zip code. Now I am having a problem getting the City and Address in a separate cell. Any ideas of how I can do this?

Comment: are there always spaces between zip, address and city? And only there?

Comment: Yes. Its pretty much just like the example.

Comment: Assuming the Address and the City could consist of multiple words, I don't think this can be done with just this info. You'd need a list of the possible cities somewhere else. Or if the Address always ended in St, Ave, etc., that would give you something to separate them on.

Comment: Indeed, how can you differentiate between the start of the city name and the end of the street name? And I mean, you personally. Are you able to distinguish them?

Comment: Well, assume the city consists of only one word, split on the last space and manually correct the rest, it is only 300 lines anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's always in that exact format, then if the city has only one word (with unlimited spaces in the address):

```
Addr:  =LEFT(A5,
        FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A5," ","~",FIND(",",A5)-1-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A5,FIND(",",A5)-1)," ","")))))
City:  =MID(A5,
        FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A5," ","~",FIND(",",A5)-1-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A5, FIND(",",A5)-1)," ",""))))+1,
        FIND(",",A5) - 1 - FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A5," ","~",FIND(",",A5)-1-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A5, FIND(",",A5)-1)," ","")))))
State: =MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+2,2)
Zip:   =RIGHT(A1,5)
```